# Authenticate to API within Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, postman

I have an API that I am able to authenticate against using the Postman client. Using Postman I am able to enter in my username and password into the header and receive back an access token.

I would like to accomplish the same authentication with a simple HTML page using Javascript. However, I am unsure how to craft the Javascript request and pass in my username and password as I did with Postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the address bar of Postman there's a link that says "Generate Code" on previous versions it was a button with a `</>` symbol.
Clicking that link opens up a popup with a dropdownlist where Javascript is one option, this will generate the code to do the request.

Comment: Thank you. That looks to be just what I was looking for.

Comment: Mark me as answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

A password is normally considered private, if you include it in your javascript anyone can read it and fire requests off to the API as your user. 
Additionally, the browsers same-origin policy - unless configured otherwise will stop you firing ajax requests to a domain other than the one the webpage was loaded from.

Instead you should create a proxy script in the server-side language of your choice hosted on your domain and fire your ajax requests off to this.
This script would do the relevant actions with the API keeping your credentials a secret and return the response.

Answer (score 0):

Let me also add to the other answers that with jQuery you can do a get request with [`$.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/), and a post request with [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/). But I would do what Vector suggests and generate the JavaScript with Postman.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with ajax call within a javascript file and you can aslo do with the xhttprequest .
example of ajax call:
                $.ajax({
                    url         : url, //URL 
                    type        : 'POST', // The HTTP Method
                    data        : array,
                    contentType : 'application/json',
                    cache       : false,
                    success     : function (data) {

```
                }, 
                error       : function (err) {

            });
```

In this you can also add the Headers where u can your api access token